# Truncation the size of linked list from '__int64' to 'size_t

Tags: c++, linked-list, size-t

I successfully wrote a C++ code for radix sort by creating 10 buckets. For the 10 buckets, I created them in this way:

```
struct node{
    struct node* next;
    long value;
};

struct node*bucket[10];

for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {  
    bucket[i] = (struct node *) malloc (1000000*sizeof(struct node));
}
```

and it is perfect done.

But then now I need to raise the amount of my buckets to 100000. I tried to modified those buckets' size like:

```
struct node*bucket[100000];

for (int i=0; i<100000; ++i) {  
    bucket[i] = (struct node *) malloc (1000000*sizeof(struct node));
}
```

But this time I think I can't even create those buckets. I am using Visual Studio to code, and this is in C++. The compiler gave me these warnings:

> : warning C4305: 'argument' : truncation from '__int64' to 'size_t'
>
> : warning C4309: 'argument' : truncation of constant value

I searched it up in the internet, somebody says the number is too big. This is the first time I handle such a large number in the linked list. Do I need to modify anything to make this code work again?

Thank you. Any ideas and help I will be appreciated!

Comment: I can't reproduce either of these warnings in VS2010. I tried both x86 and x64.

Comment: I just tried to debug it, and it gave me "Unhandled exception at 0x00301e77 in list.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow."

Comment: That would be expected because `struct node*bucket[100000];` is too large to fit on the stack. But the warnings are puzzling.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio, x86 or x64, any other special project settings?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010, and I am running 64 bits

Comment: I have a question: It doesn't has problem when you created just one *bucket[100000]. What if you create not just one *bucket[100000], but also 6 linked list of this size : head[100000], tail[100000], and 4 more. Will there be a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I turned your code into a little sample program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    struct node*bucket[100000];

    for (int i=0; i<100000; ++i) { 
        bucket[i] = (struct node *) malloc (1000000*sizeof(struct node));
    }
}
```

This compiles nicely with Visual Studio 2010.

What comes to my mind is that you're allocating an array of 100000 pointers (probably 4 bytes each). It reminds me of old compilers which wouldn't let you use more than 64kB of stack space per variable (or function? I cannot remember. It was with Turbo Pascal or Turbo C...).

Since this is C++, I suggest to just not use a raw C array in the first place. Instead, you can replace the above code with:

```
#include <vector>

struct node {
    int i;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<node> bucket( 100000 );
}
```

The `std::vector` object can be used in all cases where you'd use a C array.

Comment: For std::vector, if I define multiple vector of this size ( like 6 ), will there exist overflow as well?

Comment: @LearnMore: No. Each vector only occupies a few bytes (maybe 16 bytes for you, 8 bytes for the pointer to data and 8 bytes for a size counter) on the stack; the 100000 structs are allocated in a different memory region.

Answer (score -1):

*Probably* the problem is in the loop condition:

```
for (int i=0; i<100000; ++i)
              ^^^^^^^^^
```

You need to have `std::size_t i;` or `unsigned long i;` to compare till `100000`.

Comment: I think this is highly unlikely; this would imply that `int` is 16 bits wide. It's true that it needs to be *at least* 16 bits, but in practice it has the "native" size every except 64bit machines (where it's still 32bit).